# парсинг селекторов phpQuery

Tags: php, парсер

```
<div class="artvalue available_2">2</div>
<div class="artvalue">
    <select name="ctl00$pagecontext$ordercontrol1$ddlQuantity" id="ctl00_pagecontext_ordercontrol1_ddlQuantity" class="ddlquantity"><option value="Oddziały:  TAK">Oddziały:  TAK</option>
    <option value="Centrala: TAK">Centrala: TAK</option>
    <option value="Magazyn Rybnik: >5" disabled="" class="warehouse-item">Magazyn Rybnik: &gt;5</option>
    <option value="filia Bielsko-Biała: 3">filia Bielsko-Biała: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Jastrzębie: 3">filia Jastrzębie: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Katowice: 2">filia Katowice: 2</option>
    <option value="filia Kielce: 1">filia Kielce: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Kraków: 1">filia Kraków: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Krosno: 1">filia Krosno: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Łódź: 0">filia Łódź: 0</option>
    <option value="filia Nowy Sącz: 3">filia Nowy Sącz: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Nowy Targ: 3">filia Nowy Targ: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Ostrów Maz.: 2">filia Ostrów Maz.: 2</option>
    <option value="filia Strzelce Opolskie: 1">filia Strzelce Opolskie: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Warszawa: 4">filia Warszawa: 4</option>
    <option value="filia Wieluń: 3">filia Wieluń: 3</option>
    <option value="Magazyn Główny: TAK">Magazyn Główny: TAK</option>
    <option value="Wrocław biuro handlowe: 0">Wrocław biuro handlowe: 0</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[Оригинал кода](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9QbQWpbZX1YZXQtWXNVOHFxYTA/view?usp=sharing)

Как спарсить первую цифру "2" и селект со значением `value="Centrala: TAK`?

Comment: Обращаю ваше внимание, что весь код, относящийся к вопросу, должен быть в самом вопросе. Ссылки могут служить только дополнением

Comment: я думал так удобней будет

Comment: Внешние ссылки имеют обыкновение "умирать". Перенося код в вопрос, вы тем самым делаете вопрос достоянием общественности. Разумеется, большие куски кода имеет смысл сокращать, вычленяя из них минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: уже перенес как надо)

Answer (score 1):

Вам можно воспользоваться утилитой под названием [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Она позволяет обращаться к элементам `html` страницы через селекторы, аналогично `css` и `jquery`. Что-то похоже у них есть.

В итоге, подключив себе, код может быть к примеру такой:

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = str_get_html('<div class="artvalue available_2">2</div>
<div class="artvalue">
    <select name="ctl00$pagecontext$ordercontrol1$ddlQuantity" id="ctl00_pagecontext_ordercontrol1_ddlQuantity" class="ddlquantity"><option value="Oddziały:  TAK">Oddziały:  TAK</option>
    <option value="Centrala: TAK">Centrala: TAK</option>
    <option value="Magazyn Rybnik: >5" disabled="" class="warehouse-item">Magazyn Rybnik: &gt;5</option>
    <option value="filia Bielsko-Biała: 3">filia Bielsko-Biała: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Jastrzębie: 3">filia Jastrzębie: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Katowice: 2">filia Katowice: 2</option>
    <option value="filia Kielce: 1">filia Kielce: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Kraków: 1">filia Kraków: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Krosno: 1">filia Krosno: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Łódź: 0">filia Łódź: 0</option>
    <option value="filia Nowy Sącz: 3">filia Nowy Sącz: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Nowy Targ: 3">filia Nowy Targ: 3</option>
    <option value="filia Ostrów Maz.: 2">filia Ostrów Maz.: 2</option>
    <option value="filia Strzelce Opolskie: 1">filia Strzelce Opolskie: 1</option>
    <option value="filia Warszawa: 4">filia Warszawa: 4</option>
    <option value="filia Wieluń: 3">filia Wieluń: 3</option>
    <option value="Magazyn Główny: TAK">Magazyn Główny: TAK</option>
    <option value="Wrocław biuro handlowe: 0">Wrocław biuro handlowe: 0</option>
    </select>
</div>');

echo $html->find("div.available_2", 0)->plaintext;
echo $html->find("select", 0)->find("option[value=Centrala: TAK]", 0)->plaintext;
```

Как мы видим, я просто обратился к элементу `div` с классом `available_2` и взял у него текст из узла. С селектом поступил аналогично.

Подробные инструкции как парсером пользоваться можно найти в его же документации.

Comment: я работал с этой библиотекой-она не совсем подходит в даной ситуации.Сечас проблема в том,что если я ищу класс artvalue -то все ок,если available_2-пустой результат.(Это phpquery).

Comment: @RomaTulaydan я же вам в примере написал `find("div.available_2", 0)` все он ищет. Видимо вы что-то другое пишите.... либо покажите что вы там пишите. чтоб посмотреть.

Comment: в то то и дело,что available_2 на phpquery не находити

Comment: @RomaTulaydan без ваших попыток и показа кода, что вы конкретно делали ничем помочь вам нельзя. Что вы делали лучше написать код, выложить и показать. А пока мы ни к чему не придем. Вы делали что-то не так. ... вот http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qdcj-1mrt     Всё работает? Работает.  Так что нужно смотреть конкретно на вашем примере, почему у вас происходит провал)